# How to Break this command line operation?

Tags: windows, command-line, jboss, command-prompt

c:\jboss\bin\standalone.bat -debug >> c:\Temp\log\trial02.txt

I tried ^C & ^BREAK without success. If this was a Linux environment I would think of the processes and do a KILL. Yet in windows development I am without a idea.

Answer (score 2):

in Windows , Hold Control + C to break operation in Command Prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Your batch file is running an executable - so you need to stop the executable.
Use `taskkill` to close the cmd session, or just the executable so that the batch file continues.